# Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css

I have a Bootstrap Navbar, that I am trying to have set as simply a hamburger for the entire window except when it stretches out to about 700px (when it can show all the nabber drop downs without stacking). This works until about 400px, at which point the 'home' button and 'hamburger' seem to shift closer to the middle of the nabber, and dont drop down properly. I have tried using a pull-left and pull-right class for each but that leaves them where they are. My nav bar is as such:

[image: Nav bar screenshot]

[image: Nav bar screenshot]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
}
.navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
    display:block !important;
}
.navbar-header {
    float:none;
}
```

Comment: Check for `max-width`s set on containing parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the container inside the nav element. see the [bootstrap examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbars/)  there is a container where the two iems are closer to the middle...